# How do I debug an annotation processor in a bazel java_library rule?

Tags: bazel

I have added an annotation processor as a java_plugin and have added this into the plugins section of my java_library rule. I was wondering what are the bazel options to step through the annotation processor code and the javac compiler's code?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, in order to website's recommendations, you'd better ask questions containing a full detailed list of the things that you have done plus the point in which the issue has occurred. Also, avoid asking general questions as stack overflow is a place to ask questions mostly related to programming. If your question can be answered by a simple search delete it or ask it in other platforms of stack exchange network. Those platforms can be found [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to run bazel build with `--subcommands`. Bazel will then print out all the commands it executes during a build. You can then find the javac invocation you're interested in, copy the command line (including the `cd` part so you're in the correct directory), modify the command line to include the debugging options, and run it manually. Then you can debug it like you would any java program.

One thing to note is that bazel will print only the commands that it actually runs in that build, so if the action you're interested in is already up-to-date, you may have to delete one of its outputs (e.g. the jar output of that library) to get bazel to re-run the action.